# Como fazer um if comparando um valor com uma lista em um yml?

Tags: java, spring-boot

Recebo uma requisição e quero verificar se aquele canal está em uma lista que criei no yml.

Meu método:

```
    private void insereNome (String canal, ListaNomeWebRequest listaNomeWebRequest){
    if(canal.contains(("${canais}"))){
        listaNomeWebRequest.setStatus("OK");
    }
}
```

meu yml:

```
canais:
  abc: abc
```

Dessa forma, ele não ta conseguindo verificar se contém o canal abc para comparar. Poderiam me ajudar?

Obs: Já tentei sem o $.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sugiro você injetar os valores do seu arquivo utilizando `@ConfigurationProperties`:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="app")
public class MinhaClasse {
    private List<String> canais = new ArrayList<String>();

    public void insereNome (String canal, ListaNomeWebRequest listaNomeWebRequest){
        if( canais.contains(canal) ) {
            listaNomeWebRequest.setStatus("OK");
        }
    }

    public List<String> getCanais() {
        return this.canais;
    }
}
```

Seu arquivo yaml também está na estrutura errada, você deve utilizar uma lista conforme abaixo:

```
app:
    canais:
         - abc
         - bcd
         - cde
         - xyz
```

[Documentação do Spring Boot](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html)

---

### Edit

Atualizando para um exemplo funcional

**ConfigurationPropertiesDemoApplication.java**

```
package com.example.demo;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@SpringBootApplication
public class ConfigurationPropertiesDemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext ctxt = SpringApplication.run(ConfigurationPropertiesDemoApplication.class, args);

        ctxt.getBean(ConfigurationPropertiesExample.class).printChannels();
    }

    @Component
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "app")
    public class ConfigurationPropertiesExample {

        private List<String> channels = new ArrayList<>();

        public void printChannels() {
            System.out.println(channels);
        }

        public List<String> getChannels() {
            return channels;
        }

    }
}
```

---

**application.yaml**

```
app:
  channels:
    - abc
    - cdb
    - xyz
```

O output ao subir o projeto é o da lista de canais configurada no `application.yaml`:

```
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.5.RELEASE)

2019-06-01 18:36:44.618  INFO 1252 --- [  restartedMain] d.ConfigurationPropertiesDemoApplication : Starting ConfigurationPropertiesDemoApplication on DESKTOP-EBSB0DB with PID 1252 (C:\projects\configuration-properties-demo\target\classes started by Norton Gueno in C:\projects\configuration-properties-demo)
2019-06-01 18:36:44.620  INFO 1252 --- [  restartedMain] d.ConfigurationPropertiesDemoApplication : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-06-01 18:36:44.647  INFO 1252 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2019-06-01 18:36:45.041  INFO 1252 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2019-06-01 18:36:45.057  INFO 1252 --- [  restartedMain] d.ConfigurationPropertiesDemoApplication : Started ConfigurationPropertiesDemoApplication in 0.724 seconds (JVM running for 1.366)
[abc, cdb, xyz]
```

Comment: A noite faço um exemplo e posto no Github ;)

Comment: @MSSantana adicionei um getter que faltou na resposta, tente agora