# Como fazer um if comparando valores com uma lista que está em um yml?

Tags: java, spring-boot

Recebo uma requisição e quero verificar se aquele canal está em uma lista que criei no yml.

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "parceiros")
@Component
public class CanaisMapper {

private List<String> canais = new ArrayList<String>();

private void verificaCanal(String canal, Status status){
    if(canais.contains(canal)) {
        status.setStatus("OK");
    }
  }
}
```

meu yml:

```
parceiros:
  canais:
    - abc
```

Estou tomando NullPointer. Se no if eu coloco if(canal == "abc"), funciona. Mas eu quero pegar dessa lista do yml para inserir mais canais com essa condição.

Poderiam me ajudar?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como fazer um if comparando um valor com uma lista em um yml?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/388020/como-fazer-um-if-comparando-um-valor-com-uma-lista-em-um-yml)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Falta incluir um getter para a lista de canais:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "parceiros")
@Component
public class CanaisMapper {

    private List<String> canais = new ArrayList<String>();

    private void verificaCanal(String canal, Status status){
        if(canais.contains(canal)) {
            status.setStatus("OK");
        }
    }

    public List<String> getCanais() {
        return this.canais;
    }
}
```

[Documentação do Spring Boot](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html)

---

### Edit

Atualizando para um exemplo funcional

**ConfigurationPropertiesDemoApplication.java**

```
package com.example.demo;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@SpringBootApplication
public class ConfigurationPropertiesDemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext ctxt = SpringApplication.run(ConfigurationPropertiesDemoApplication.class, args);

        ctxt.getBean(ConfigurationPropertiesExample.class).printChannels();
    }

    @Component
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "app")
    public class ConfigurationPropertiesExample {

        private List<String> channels = new ArrayList<>();

        public void printChannels() {
            System.out.println(channels);
        }

        public List<String> getChannels() {
            return channels;
        }

    }
}
```

---

**application.yaml**

```
app:
  channels:
    - abc
    - cdb
    - xyz
```

O output ao subir o projeto é o da lista de canais configurada no `application.yaml`:

```
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.5.RELEASE)

2019-06-01 18:36:44.618  INFO 1252 --- [  restartedMain] d.ConfigurationPropertiesDemoApplication : Starting ConfigurationPropertiesDemoApplication on DESKTOP-EBSB0DB with PID 1252 (C:\projects\configuration-properties-demo\target\classes started by Norton Gueno in C:\projects\configuration-properties-demo)
2019-06-01 18:36:44.620  INFO 1252 --- [  restartedMain] d.ConfigurationPropertiesDemoApplication : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-06-01 18:36:44.647  INFO 1252 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2019-06-01 18:36:45.041  INFO 1252 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2019-06-01 18:36:45.057  INFO 1252 --- [  restartedMain] d.ConfigurationPropertiesDemoApplication : Started ConfigurationPropertiesDemoApplication in 0.724 seconds (JVM running for 1.366)
[abc, cdb, xyz]
```

Comment: Adicionei o getter, está exatamente assim e to tomando nullpointter.
Usando o debugger, canais está canais: size = 0 :(

Comment: @MSSantana inclui um exemplo funcional